# word usage “only”

Tags: sentence-usage, adverb-placement

I believe, *Only* mostly means as one of its kind. Correct me if I am wrong.
Last week, I texted my friend asking her where she was she replied
I am at home only. Sometimes I see people using it in terms like I am at the railway station only or  I am the park only. Is this way of using **only** correct

Comment: It would require a ridiculously contrived context for ***I am at home only*** to be idiomatically valid. Almost certainly, you're only hearing these usages from non-native speakers. Don't copy them.

Comment: This could be a case of an [eggcorn](https://metro.co.uk/2015/04/09/a-damp-squid-for-all-intensive-purposes-14-eggcorns-to-make-you-laugh-5141384/), when you misunderstand an unfamiliar word by swapping it with a more familiar one *home/station/park* ***only***  ---> *I'm at home/(the) station/(the) park* ***alone***

Answer (score 5):

This isn’t a correct way of saying only.

In these cases, rather than saying ‘only’ you would say ‘alone’;

*I am at home alone.*

*I am at the railway station alone.*

You could also say:

*I am **the only person** at home.*

*I am **the only person** at the railway station.*

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only), only can be used in two ways:

- as an adjective, meaning that there is a single one of something.
- as an adverb, meaning 'not more'

When it is used as an adjective, it normally occurs before a noun:

> This is my **only** pen

Adverb positioning is a lot more flexible, for example:

> Only a fool would believe his story!
> I only have one pen
> It's only a game
> This club is for members only.

I can't think of any way that you could use the adjectival meaning in your friend's sentence.

If she meant that she was not doing anything more interesting than sitting at home, the normal position would be after the be-verb:

> I am only at home

Comment: While the last is the better word order, it still seems unidiomatic to use "only" for this. I think "just" would be more common.

Comment: @Barmar, "Members only" is a normal phrase in US English, maybe even a set phrase.  Saying it's just for members wouldn't be out of place either, but I wouldn't be willing to guess which one is more common.

Comment: @Karen True. There's no general rule, as with many English phrases.

Comment: @Karen yes, members only is a set phrase.  No need to guess which is more common. just for members is very uncommon in written English. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=members+only%2C+just+for+members&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmembers%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20for%20members%3B%2Cc0